Unable to Deploy with Correct AWS Profile Using SAM CLI - Profile Switching Issues
I'm trying to deploy a Lambda application to different environments (test and prod) using AWS SAM CLI. However, I'm running into issues where the deployment is not using the correct AWS account/profile. Below are the details of the problem and the solutions I've attempted so far.
Problem:
When I run sam deploy --config-env prod --profile tale-garden-prod, it consistently deploys to the wrong AWS account. Additionally, when I run aws sts get-caller-identity --profile tale-garden-prod, it returns an incorrect account ID.
Solutions I've Tried:
Reconfiguring AWS CLI Profile:
I used aws configure --profile tale-garden-prod to re-enter the correct IAM user credentials (Access Key and Secret Access Key).
I checked the ~/.aws/credentials and ~/.aws/config files to ensure the correct details are present.
Verifying Authentication:
I ran aws sts get-caller-identity --profile tale-garden-prod to verify which AWS account I was connected to using the specified profile.
Setting Profile via Environment Variables:
I set the profile using the command export AWS_PROFILE=tale-garden-prod and then tried deploying again:
export AWS_PROFILE=tale-garden-prod
sam deploy --config-env prod

This did not resolve the issue either.
Checking for MFA:
MFA (Multi-Factor Authentication) is not enabled on my account, so I ruled out this potential issue.
SAM Build and Deploy:
I used sam build --profile tale-garden-prod to specify the correct profile during the build process, and then proceeded with the deployment. However, it still did not connect to the correct AWS account.

"when I run aws sts get-caller-identity --profile tale-garden-prod, it returns an incorrect account ID" get-caller-identity isn't going to lie and or get confused.  If it gives you the wrong account ID, that means you entered the wrong credentials for tale-garden-prod.

Redefining config and credentials solved
